# what module will help me to analyze this data?

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file which holds many records and there are many other csv files which holds the same records but with their different values. I want to analyze and to get some useful information from these csv files but do not know how to do it? How to do it?

csv file is like

```
Compony name,DCP,OpenMarket,HIGH,LOW,CURRENT_MARKET,CHANGE,VOLUME
Company Moon, 8.07, 9.07, 9.07, 7.80, 8.22, 0.15, 4547500
Company Sun, 7.07, 6.07, 5.07, 3.80, 7.22, 0.10, 1233333
.
.
.
```

This is one csv file containing information about some companies data in stock market. Another csv file holds same companies data but with different values . I want to get information according to their change,Volume and others prop to know which company is going Good.

Comment: what do you mean by `statistical data`?

Comment: your query is pretty vague: what kind of differences are you looking for? what kind of statistics are you trying to show?
for most data tasks, pandas is the go-to library. You can load 2 files and look for differences row by row, column by column etc...

Comment: check out `pandas`... `NumPy` and `Matplotlib` will most likely be helpful as well.

Comment: Also, from your "machine-learning" tag, you probably want to do some EDA tasks. You can search on google _exploratory data analysis_ keywords. You can also find some valuable notebooks on kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/search?q=exploratory+data+analysis).

Comment: @MrE I have not two files it more than two files. I am looking for difference how much change is occurred in each value of records.

Comment: @learner Yes I want the same.

Comment: @Flow statistical data means to get some valuable information

Comment: Asking for library suggestions is off-topic for StackOverflow and saying something has `useful information` is very vague. If you really want answers, give proper examples and explain what you want to do.

Comment: Agreed. It would help if you edit the question to include examples of what the CSV files contain. Not the full data, obviously, but paste a few lines from a few of the files so we understand what kind of data you're working with, and then give an example of what kind of "useful information" you want to extract from those files.

Comment: @Hippo ok csv data added now what about now

Answer (score 2):

using pandas, if you want to diff cell by cell, and assuming the 2 files have the same number of rows / columns, I would do the following:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')

# join the 2 dataframes to get a single dataframe
df = df1.join(df2, rsuffix='_2')
# columns will now be A,B,C and A_2, B_2, C_2 respectively
# check for diff with 
df['A-diff'] = df['A'] - df['A_2']
# ...
# or to do it all:
for col in df1.columns:
  df[f'{col}-diff'] = df[col] - df['{col}_2']
#df['<column name>-diff'] has the diff for each column
```

I'm showing a simple substraction, but you can do whatever you want with the 2 columns. The point is to get the merged values in one dataframe to operate on them.

ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html